# SQL Server Detect Transactions and Commit?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions

I have a long-running script that may or may not have an uncomitted transaction at the end. I would like to have something at the bottom to just clean up and if there is a transaction hanging out somewhere, just commit it, and if there is one another level up, commit that one, etc.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how your code is structured such that transactions could be left 'hanging', as opposed to committed or rolled back? Perhaps some code with the transaction-related stuff included would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop until all commuted. Strange situation to be in though...

```
 WHILE XACT_STATE() = 1
      COMMIT TRAN
```